# UICollectionView scrollsToTop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

On my controller I have two `UICollectionView` instances and one `UITableView` instance. When tableView is on top of view hierarchy and I tap on status bar it does not scroll to top.

I've tried to set `scrollsToTop` property for collectionViews to `NO`. But tableView still doesn't scroll to top. Even more: collectionViews still scroll when I tap status bar.

I've gone further. I created a category on `UIScrollView`, where I swizzled `-didMoveToWindow` method like this:

```
- (void)swizzled_didMoveToWindow
{
    [self swizzled_didMoveToWindow];
    self.scrollsToTop = NO;
}
```

And it didn't work too! Scroll to top by tapping on status bar still works for all `UICollectionView` instances!

Please, tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the collection view(s) also within a scrollview by any chance? I  had same issue, though my collectionView was within a scrollview and I had to set self.scrollView.scrollToTop=NO; before it actually stopped scrolling

Comment: @JimTierney, I thought about it. I didn't get too deep and don't know, may be some PKRevealViewController has its child view controllers on scrollView. But on current viewController there is no any scrollViews

Comment: @JimTierney, but wait. I've said that I've swizzled -didMoveToWindow method for the whole UIScrollView class. Thus no scrollView, tableView or collectionView should have scrollsToTop property set to YES